# Locus points with a distance $d$ from a plane $\alpha$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have to show the locus of the points $P$ from a distance $d$ of a plane $\alpha$ are the union of two parallel planes to $\alpha$.

What I did: since
$$\alpha\colon ax+by+cz+\tilde{d}=0$$
then the normal vector of $\alpha$ is $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$. Also, I know
$$d_{\alpha,P}=\frac{|ax+by+cz+\tilde{d}|}{\underbrace{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}_{=K}}=d\Rightarrow|ax+by+cz+\tilde{d}|=\underbrace{K\cdot d}_{=M}$$

Hence
$$ax+by+cz+\tilde{d}=M\Rightarrow ax+by+cz+(\tilde{d}-M)=0$$
or
$$ax+by+cz+\tilde{d}=-M\Rightarrow ax+by+cz+(\tilde{d}+M)=0$$
which are both equations of planes with normal $(a,b,c)$, therefore, parallels to $\alpha$.

Is it correct?